# How to get annotations declared on self

Tags: java, annotations

Given an example class:

```
public class MyClass {
    @MyAnnotation
    public OtherClass field;
}
```

is there a way to reach annotations declared on `field` from within `field` itself? I know it could be done via:

```
new MyClass().getClass().getFields()[0].getDeclaredAnnotations()
```

but I am looking for a more straightforward solution.
Being `field`, how to get Annotations that were declared on me? Code-wise I'd see it like this

```
new MyClass().field.getAnnotationsDeclaredOnMe();
```

Comment: Why don't you just write a helper? Based on whether you use the index on the `getFields()`, or the `getField(String name)` method, writing something like `getAnnotations(clazz, fieldName/index)` should not be too hard.

Comment: No, there's not. After all, the object and its reference aren't specific to that field; they could be held in many different places.

Comment: @midor well if there is no way to do it directly, then I imagine a helper method would suffice.

Comment: Since the `Class` and `Field` classes explicitly store meta-information about a class and its components, while the actual classes and fields store their values, I would be very surprised if there was a way to do that. I mean you can do `MyClass().getClass().getField("myField").getDeclaredAnnotations()`, which in my opinion is more clear, but the meta-information on the `Field` is only available in the respective reference of type `Field` not in the field itself.